# Auto complate quotation and parentheses in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

quotation in Android studio are like this:

```
System.out.println(");
```

[image]

And I want it like this

```
System.out.println(" ");
```

[image]

cursor go inside the quotation

It also about Curly brackets and parentheses

Comment: Settings->Editor->General->Smart keys-> Insert pair bracket/quote

Comment: thank you @Luksprog for answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable Insert Pair quote from settings as follows:

[image: pair quote]

Click on Ok after selection